# Вывод кастомного html/php после одной конкретной категории

Tags: wordpress

Есть две категории: "Яблоки" и "Бананы". Каждая выводится на свою страницу. Как мне вывести

### Hello, world

после категории Бананов? Чтобы после категории яблок этот код не появлялся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то это должно выглядеть так:

```
if (get_term_by( 'slug', 'banana', 'category' )) {
   echo "Hello, world";
}
//Или
$cat = get_term_by( 'slug', 'banana', 'category' );
if($cat) {
   echo "Hello, world";
}
```

[Подробнее](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_term_by)

Comment: Попробовал, hello, world появился на всех страницах. Может быть к категории необходимо по id обратиться? (код вставил в functions.php)

Comment: Зачем functions.php. Он нужен в шаблоне категорий как раз в том месте где нуден вывод Hello, world

Comment: Понял, получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое - создать [шаблон рубрики](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2#.D0.9E.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.80.D1.83.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B8) `category-banana.php`,
где `banana` - слаг рубрики.

В этот шаблон добавить что нужно.

Comment: Может быть существует какой-нибудь хук, чтобы прицепиться к конкретной категории в момент ее вывода?

Comment: Стоп, а если я в слаг укажу не слаг категории, а слаг страницы?

Comment: @SudoTrololo страницы и рубрики - это разные вселенные.